# If refresh the page, a 404 error message will appear

Tags: nginx

When I visit a website at `https//mysite.com:8080`, redirects to the `/login` page, and everything works fine.

But as soon as I refresh the page I get an error:

> {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /login","error":"Not Found"}

How can this be fixed?

```
server {
  listen 8080 ssl;

  ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/chain.pem;

  error_page 497 301 =307 https://my-site.com:8080$request_uri;

  server_name my-site.com;

  root /home/username/apps/project/client/dist;

  index index.html;

  location @app {
     proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9900;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    error_page 405 @app;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config looks like a dirty hack to join frontend and backend web apps together. Usually you should differentiate frontend and backend calls according to the URI prefix, something like

```
location /api/ {
   proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9900;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

However you can try to use the second dirty hack like this one:

```
location @app {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9900;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 = /index.html;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    error_page 405 @app;
}
```

As being said, this is only a hack and better to be avoided due to the performance considerations.